# Command with user input in a command

Tags: discord.js

The title may sound confusing, but the thing is that i'm trying to do a quiz game. You should write *quiz and a random question would pop up. The only thing I can't figure out is how do i check if the answear is right. An example is:

```
User:*quiz
Bot:Am I a good bot?
         1.yes
         2.no
User:1
Bot:Correct answear
```

I don't know how to check if the user sent another message during the same command. The bot should wait for the user to enter his message. Can somebody help me? I'll be really thankful.

Comment: You could use reactions to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last message of a user with the following method:

```
let lastMessage = member.lastMessage;
```

Than you can do something like this:

```
if(lastMessage.content === '1') {
    message.channel.send('Correct answer.');
} else if(lastMessage.content === '2') {
    message.channel.send('Wrong answer.');
}
```

Comment: this will check the message ,,*quiz", but i managed to work it out. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: no, this won't check the message quiz, when you execute this method after the answer of the user. you just need to find the right point to execute the method.